# Is there is a way to rename a visual studio project in one step ? (Automate renaming)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, automation, rename

I have been searching for a way to rename a visual studio project (vb.net) in one easy step, all i found were a tutorials that make me rename all files in the projects.

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b actually i have to open the project folder and change every file name to the new one like here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZaaRFvsb6o

Comment: There's no one-step procedure to do that.

Comment: There isn't a one click solution in Visual Studio, so you can request a feature in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the question you want answered is actually different to the question you asked. The answer to the question you actually asked is that you right-click the project in the Solution Explorer, select Rename and then enter the new name. That's it, that's all. Project renamed.

If that doesn't answer the question you actually want answered, I suggest that you actually ask that question instead.

Comment: I suspect he also wants namespaces, default namespaces, assembly name etc fixed. And that cascades down through all files. I suspect there may be Roslyn rules that can help perform the work in fewer steps, but generally this isn't as easy ar renaming the project file.

Comment: @jessehouwing, I suspect you're right, which I alluded to in my answer. We shouldn't have to guess or make assumptions though. As I stated, if someone wants a particular question answered, that is the question they should actually ask. That means including ALL the relevant details of the problem. I have answered the question that was asked.